# Изменение кол-ва элементов в массиве

Tags: c, массивы

Представим что есть массив, будь то символьный или целочисленный. Пользователь вводит последовательность цифр (символов) и если он введет 3 символа, то размер массива должен стать равным 3. Если 5, то размер массива должен стать 5 и т.д

Как это можно реализовать в Си? Прошу хотя бы какой-нибудь простой пример.

Comment: Думаю, динамические массивы подойдут

Comment: В том учебнике, который я посоветовал в вашем прошлом вопросе, это описано.

Comment: Можно почитать [статью на википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Динамический_массив), например. Там есть пример кода на C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой массив должен быть выделен в куче, а не объявлен как `int a[100]`, грубо говоря. Создавайте его с помощью вызова `malloc`.

Далее - храните размер массива. При необходимости добавить в него элемент - увеличивайте его с помощью `realloc`, соответственно изменяя значение переменной размера, и дописывайте нужный элемент.

Если такие операции частые - то лучше хранить размер выделенной памяти (в том числе зарезервированной для будущих элементов) и количество элементов в массиве, и выделять память с запасом - скажем, когда свободные места исчерпаны, удваивать память для массива. Так вы получаете амортизированное константное количество копирований элементов.